# Diameter of Three Inscribed Circles

Tags: geometry

What is the diameter of a circle in which are inscribed three smaller identical circles, two of which are on one side of a chord, the third on the other side?  This problem came up when cutting a log into billets for turning table legs.  I tried including a diagram but the reputation Nazis won't let me.

[image]

Comment: Note that $DEA$ are all on one line, tangent to circles $F,H$ and perpendicular to BC.  Because of the right angles, the tangents from $E$ to $F,H$ are the radius of the small circles.  Chord $BC$ is four times the radius of the small circles.

Comment: None of the above relies on the tangency at $G$, which will define everything.

Comment: @Blue:  You are right about $FH$, but the more I look at it, $BC$ must be shorter than four small radii.  Note that $E$ is toward $D$ from $A$, so the angle between BC and the circle on the side of $FH$ is greater than $\frac \pi 2$

Comment: @RossMillikan: My thinking was a little messed-up. I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the radius of the small circle, $s$ the distance from the center of the large circle to the chord, and $t$ the distance from the center of the large circle to the center of one of the two small tangent circles:

[image: Log-Cutting Diagram]

Clearly $t = r + s$, and also $t^2 = r^2 + \left(r-s\right)^2$, and we have

$$\left( r + s \right)^2 = r^2 + \left( r - s \right)^2$$

so that, after a tiny bit of algebra,

$$4 s = r$$

The radius of the large circle is therefore $2r+s = \frac{9}{4}r$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the small radius be $r$ and the distance from the center of the large circle to $BC$ be $x$. Positions the center of the large circle at the origin with BC horizontal and below the $x$ axis.  Then the center of the upper right small circle is $(1,1-x)$.  Draw the line from $A$ though this point and it will meet the large circle at the point of tangency.  The radius of the large circle is $2+x$, looking at the bottom circle.  The point of tangency is then $(\frac {2+x}{\sqrt{2-2x+x^2}},\frac {(2+x)(1-x)}{\sqrt{2-2x+x^2}})$.  Demanding this be at distance $1$ from the center of the small circle gives $(\frac {2+x}{\sqrt{2-2x+x^2}}-1)^2+(\frac {(2+x)(1-x)}{\sqrt{2-2x+x^2}}-(1-h))^2=1$ which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%282%2bx-sqrt%282-2x%2bx%5E2%29%29%5E2%2b%28%282%2bx%29%281-x%29-%281-x%29sqrt%282-2x%2bx%5E2%29%29%5E2=2-2x%2bx%5E2) solves with $x=\frac 14$.  This says the radius of the large circle is $\frac 94$ the radius of the smaller.